# How to prevent multiple users access same file

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety

I am uploading a file in the `Servlet`, doing the necessary operations on this file, and then downloading this processed file to the client.

I have two forms `multipart / form-data`. The first one uses the post method to upload files. The second one is using the get method to download the file.

`DoPost ()` -> The user selects and uploads the file. This file is processed and stored in the specified location. And this file is kept as a global variable of type `File`.

`DoGet ()` -> Downloading the global `File`.

When a user uploads a file from Web browser, another user can download it from another Web browser.
I suppose this may be the reason that File is global. I tried `ThreadLocal`, but it did not work because `doPost` and `doGet` are not in the same thread.

Is there a way you can suggest?

Comment: To clarify, am I correct that you want the file only to be available to the uploader?

Comment: Yes, only the uploader.

Comment: Your question is not about multiple threads. It is about multiple *users.*

Comment: I changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user will upload and download the file in the same session, then you can save the filename in HttpSession during the POST operation. During the GET, you check for the existence in HttpSession. Let the user download the file only if it exists in HttpSession.

If the user could have uploaded the file, then logged out and logged back in and download the file, then you will need to save the file information in some persistence storage like a database.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct each request is a different thread, however they should be linked to the same session.Store your file in the session and all will be sorted.